# Integer value comparison with null vallue

Tags: java, integer, compareto

Hi I had a question related to Integer comparison.

say I have two Integer count1 and count2, I want to implement the following action:

```
if (count1 bigger than count2)
    do something;
else
    do something else;
```

I know I can use count1.compareTo(count2) > 0. however, when count1 or count2 is a null value, program will return a NullPointerException. Is there a way to implement that if count1 or count2 is a null value, return false when doing comparison between count1 and count2?

Comment: Check if they are `null`...

Comment: ^ if(count1 == null || count2 == null) then return false. Simples

Comment: check count1 bigger than count2...i.e. `if(count1>count2)`

Answer (score 5):

I think you want:

```
if (count1 != null && count2 != null && count1 > count2)
    do something;
else
    do something else;
```

Java will auto un-box the `Integer` objects to `int` primitive values to make the mathematical `>` comparison.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to implement that if count1 or count2 is a null value, return false

```
if (count1 == null || count2 == null) return false;
if (count1 > count2)
   doSomething();
else
   doSomethingElse();
```